# Cambiar de JPanel desde Splash Screen

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en java con el IDE NetBeans y JPanel, lo que sucede es que tengo una SplashScreen que debería aparecer durante 5 segundos al inicio y luego desaparecer para darle paso a la siguiente clase Startup.
he desarrollado el siguiente código;

```
    splash Splash =new splash();
    Splash.setVisible(true);
    startUp Startup=new startUp();
    for (int sec = 0; sec <= 10; sec++) {
        Thread.sleep(sec);
        if (sec==10) {
            Splash.setVisible(false);
            Startup.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando ejecuto, aparecen ambas Startup y SplashScreen juntas, sin poder esperar los 10 segundos que aparece en el algoritmo, soy bastante nuevo en java y estoy atrapado ;( si necesitan el código completo, estoy atento para postear.

Comment: la función sleep recibe milisegundos como parámetro, no segundos. Además en tu código, en la primera vuelta del bucle esperas 0 milisegundos, en la segunda 1, en la tercera 2... Con lo que aun multiplicando por 1000 para que fueran segundos, no va a esperar 10, sino mucho más.

Comment: Gracias... Logré arreglar el tema de los segundos, pero cuando pasan los 10s aparece Startup aún así la splash screen se queda ahí, creo que el loop sigue y no deja que desaparezca la splash inclusive si le hago un "break" al loop

Comment: El `for` termina sí o sí cuando `sec` llega a `11`. Cuando vale `10` entra en el `if`, y en el `11` se sale del `for`. Lo que pase con los `JPanel` ya no sé... Faltaría información para poder responderte alguien algo.

Comment: logré solucionarlo, cambiando el argumento a "false" en el main (new startUp().setVisible(false)), muchas gracias igual.